# Problems installing Windows 7 on Dell Inspiron 531 desktop

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron

I am having a problem installing Windows 7 on a Dell Inspiron 531 desktop. I got the setup to run and now it was trying to restart and now the computer just beeps. Two times a second, one right after the other. The beep is not like a key is being held down. And the computer isn't showing anything on the screen.
edit:
this is a computer I am trying to fix there where two blue screen errors that I know of.
the first one had something to do with a display driver
the  second one was unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a bios post, maybe some hardware failed, download the Dell diagnostics and create a bootable CD or usb drive, then boot from it and run the hardware diagnostics.

[Dell Diagnostics](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R192862&SystemID=INSP_DSKTP_D531&servicetag=&os=WLH&osl=en&deviceid=3841&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=8&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=13&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=265259)

EDIT:

If no joy:

If there is a battery backup or power strip being used, remove it.

You will need to strip it down, disconnect everything from the mobo except 1 memory module, processor video card (use the onboard if it has it) pull all add in cards except the video card if that is the only source of video (note their slot position) disconnect hard drives and optical, see if you get a bios post and error, if you do you have a fault memory stick or other hardware you removed. Add them back one at a time until you get a no post again.

If no post try the other memory module

If this does not get a post suspect your video is bad, try another add in video card to verify.

Last but not least, try another power supply.

If none of this works I suspect your motherboard has failed.

.

Comment: i stuck the hdd in to another computer and finished installing windows do you think that that would fix the problem?

Comment: I don't actually know what the problem is, but give it a try.

Comment: i did that i let it set over night i pluged it up and it ran then i restarted it and now it doesnt work it just beeps like it did before

Comment: it wont even post now

Comment: i have tried an external video card still no post

Comment: i finally got it to post with 1gb of memory and the hdd plugged in

Comment: now hopefully i will get the rest of the memory in and the cd rom working

Comment: Sounds like a bad memory module, replace the defective one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just to keep trying to install it. If you've tried this multiple times, there's an FAQ on the Microsoft site that might offer some additional ideas: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-7-installation-problems-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: i cant even see the bios screen

Comment: Disconnect the hard drive, see if you get a bios post now.

Comment: yes i now see the bios screen

Comment: now that i put the hdd back in the computer went back to beeping

Comment: check my edit in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the beeping is coming from mother board because of a issue with a little dirt,dust,etc. In the memory sticks. Unlock the memory sticks one at a time use compressed can of air with short bursts of air to clean out the memory channel the memory stick locks into.Make use to not mix up the order.